# Creating an AKS Cluster using C#?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have not found a way to do so using C# K8s SDK:  https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp

How to create a AKS Cluster in C#? Basically, the following command:

```
az aks create -g $RESOURCE_GROUP -n $AKS_CLUSTER \
    --enable-addons azure-keyvault-secrets-provider \
    --enable-managed-identity \
    --node-count $AKS_NODE_COUNT \
    --generate-ssh-keys \
    --enable-pod-identity \
    --network-plugin azure
```

Comment: You can use this [url for aks using c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/aks-dotnet-manage-kubernetes-cluster/getting-started-on-managing-kubernetes-clusters-aks-using-c/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a PUT request with payload (JSON body) to ARM.
See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managed-clusters/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP